# How do I make a WP8.1 app start at a different page on launch?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

So I have a login page and a main page.  On the launch of the app, I want to check to see if the app has a token saved and if not launch to login page.

In WP8.1 Silverlight I used to use

```
RootFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(RootFrame_Navigating);
```

and then

```
void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/Pages/MainPage.xaml") != true)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (token != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (token == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            });
        }
    }
```

What's the best way to do this in a WP8.1 runtime app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs under the OnLaunched method you may check if user have token. Then you may decide to navigate user to Login or else.

```
     if (youruserdonthavetokenstoredindborlocal)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Login));
        }
     else
        {
           rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```